# Installing Adobe CS5.5 Master Collection on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Xenial Xerus

Tags: photoshop

I know this has been asked for the older versions, but the solutions for those dont appear to work for this.

I'm kinda of new to Ubuntu and Linux, but the Wine system seems pretty straight-forward. Everytime I try and run the installation of CS5.5, however, I receive an "Error (-1) Restart the system and try the installation again." The .exercise opens fine, and it starts to install the beginning components, but after about 30 seconds, the error pops up. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing some core components?

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17

Comment: Current Wine doesn't run on those rules. Partial installation components are accepted, but even when I remove the 64-bit options it still pops the error.

Comment: Please check the link in the first comment. Anything there below Gold is a waste of time. You may know that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. You are doing something wrong. I.E. trying to install software under WINE that doesn't work under WINE. I understand your frustration as I have had a similar experience with a software package I needed that also would not run under WINE. While your options are limited in this regard, you do have options.

**1. Virtual Machine.**

You can install Virtual Box and install a copy of Windows in a virtual machine and then install your software. (This is the option I used when I had a requirement for an Access Database that also would not run under WINE)

**2. Dual boot**

This is a similar solution that requires installation of Windows alongside    Ubuntu. This approach has some technical issues as Windows will ignore Ubuntu and act as if there is nothing in the partition that your Ubuntu installation resides in. Due to the very real possibility that Windows will destroy your Ubuntu during installation this course of action is only viable for those who:

A) Have a tried and true backup and restore plan.

and

B) Are capable of either handling multiple drives with finesse or planning  and executing partitioning plans.

3. Visit [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and use the assistance there to help you locate open source software that will accomplish the tasks you would be using Adobe CS 5.5 Master Collection for (for example [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) to accomplish tasks you would use Photoshop for under Windows)